# GCC how to suppress " discards 'volatile' qualifier from pointer target type"

Tags: c, gcc, volatile

How can i suppress this warning?
maybe some #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored in code or CFLAG in makefile?

Comment: I don't suppose plan-A, proper structuring the code so this warning isn't emitted in the first place, is an option. Warnings mean things. In nearly all cases it is indicative of a logic bug; not just advice for casual consideration. That said, minimizing the affected source where specific warnings are being squelched would be preferred. Isolate the function, possibly in its own source, and use something like `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdiscarded-qualifiers` in as tight a proximity as you can. Don't throw the baby out with the bath water.

Comment: Using a cast avoids this warning in GCC. So the fact you are getting it suggests it is arising in an automatic conversion, as in assignment. That is a trouble sign. A warning is the compiler saying “I have the ability to do this, but it may not be what you want.” You should take it as an indication there may be a semantic problem—a bug—in your program, in which case the proper course of action is to fix the bug, not to suppress the message. If you truly need to remove a qualifier, then use an explicit cast. But be sure you know the consequences of that.

Answer (score 1):

If you had posted the full warning message it should show the specific warning `[-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]`. Like other warnings, just prefix with `no-` to suppress it.

From the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options)

> -Wno-discarded-qualifiers (C and Objective-C only)
>
> Do not warn if type qualifiers on pointers are being discarded. Typically, the compiler warns if a const char * variable is passed to a function that takes a char * parameter. This option can be used to suppress such a warning.

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int a;
volatile int *p = &a;

int main (void)
{
        int *q = p;
        return 0;
}

$ gcc test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:8:11: warning: initialization discards ‘volatile’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
  int *q = p;
           ^
$ gcc -Wno-discarded-qualifiers test.c
$
```

Comment: While this does answer the question asked, please do not tell people how to disable warnings without cautioning them that there are reasons for the warnings and this may leave their program broken. This warning should not be disabled without an understanding of why it occurs and why discarding a qualifier is necessary in the program. Generally, it should not be necessary, and the warning should not be disabled.

Comment: Further, a better solution is simply to use an explicit cast. This narrows the exclusion of the warning to a single point in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Although you probably already know it is a bad programming tactic, you can disable warnings in general when compiling and not only the one that bugs you.

> Add -w option when compiling

I also attach you the documentation on Warnings Options.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Hope i helped!

Answer (score -1):

`-Wdiscarded-qualifiers` did not really help me.
actually I've tried to find it in gcc documentation, but I am not good at this.

Here are my cflags in project

```
CFLAGS ?= -g0 -O3 -Wno-discarded-qualifiers -Wshadow -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-function  -Wno-error=strict-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-error=cpp -Wuninitialized -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wtype-limits -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wno-cast-qual -Wunreachable-code -Wno-switch-default -Wno-switch-enum -Wreturn-type -Wmultichar -Wformat-security -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-error=pedantic -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-error=missing-prototypes -Wdouble-promotion -Wclobbered -Wdeprecated -Wempty-body -Wtype-limits -Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wuninitialized -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wtype-limits -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Wno-cast-qual -Wunreachable-code -Wno-switch-default -Wreturn-type -Wmultichar -Wformat-security -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-sign-compare 
LDFLAGS ?= -lm
```

and the reason that I am using discard volatile qualifiers is that I don't want to add volatile in function prototypes and don't want to cast it in function call, because some of the variables work fine without volatile key, and others don't.
(it's some common variables and also thread_t types)
So the code works fine, also when I've tried to cast volatile types in function call - there some glitches happened, and now all works fine. Thanks for help I appreciate that!

Now with that key I have

```
discards 'volatile' qualifier from pointer target type
```

it's a pointer that sometimes gets optimized by compiler.

Comment: `there some glitches happened, and now all works fine` Sorry, but this sounds like it comes from misunderstanding how `volatile` works and how C language works. C language has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) - that something "works" now is not enough, it may break any minute and break other parts of code. The general suggestion is to learn what `volatile` does when to use it and how it works and instead of removing warnings -> write properly structured code so you do not have such warnings in the first place.

Comment: Smart people added warnings so that the compiler is smarter and _warns_ about unsafe code. The warning is there telling you "there is a problem in your code, fix _your code_". Disabling the warning sounds as like ignoring early signs of a catastrophe. When you explicitly cast the `volatile` out of a pointer type that means "yea, I know what I'm doing, there is no reason for a warning here" - that's why casts are used.

Comment: there us no undefined behavior.  just compiler that can optimize some of variables, and something is not working. for example there was a common code for threading operation in linux. thread_t was not volatile - and didnt work, ive added volatile - and thread started to work fine. 
my program works for an days and works fine, so i think i know what i am douing.